# Are there any area in arxiv without requiring endorsement?

Tags: preprint

Are there any areas in arxiv to post without endorsement?

Comment: If you have affiliation with an academic or research institution, then submitting with your institutional email ID will often waive the requirements for you. (see https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement)

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you have to get an endorsement to post on arxiv. After you have an endorsement in a specific area, you can crosslist your paper in other areas, which will give you the ability to post and give your own endorsements in different areas.